# Ansible sudo run ("as root") on Cygwin

Tags: ssh, ansible, cygwin, sudo

Need to run bash-script at sudo-user on remote hosts using Ansible. My working machine is Win10 + Cygwin (sorry, it wasn't my fault).

So, i tested it on non-sudo scripts (it doesn't need root access) - and it works.
No, first time it didn't work at all: `Failed to connect to the host via ssh: my_user@server1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)`

So, i used this: `"ssh-keygen -t rsa" -> "ssh-copy-id my_user@server1" || "ssh-copy-id my_user@server2"` under my_user: created an ssh-key and shered it to remote hosts. After that i could run scripts under my_user on server1, server2 and so on...

Now, i need run sudo-scripts. But i can't understand, how it'll be.

1. on Cygwin there're no ROOT-user. And i don't know, how can to generete ssh-key for nonexistent user.
2. how to run ansible playbook with root? `remote_user: root` goes with error: `Failed to connect to the host via ssh: my_user@server1: Permission denied` Look, it's my_user, not root. Does it run as my_user or root-user?
3. Maybe i do it wrong at all, and are there any "best practice"-vay to run sudo-scripts?

Oh, please, give me a help to solve my problem.

Comment: So, i find next: 1. set `become: true` to playbook, 2.use -K attr `ansible-playbook ./fluentd_install.yml -K` It runs with asking sudo(?) password and then exec scripts.
Sorry, i have a problem with uninstall now, so i can't check if task ran right. But it ran.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like auth as root disabled on remote server.
In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` find `PermitRootLogin` and set it on Yes, but I'll not recommend you to do that.

Actually, use exactly root user - it's bad practice.

Check permissions for your `my_user`. Maybe you can grant it sudo rights without password.

To do that edit `/etc/sudoers` as root, find this line:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
```

And after it add this:

```
my_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

After it you'll be able to execute any sudo command without password on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, but what i did?
So, steps of solution:

1. set `become: true` at playbook, abuote here:

   hosts:
       test_hosts
   become: true
   vars:
2. Next, run playbook with "-K" attibute: `ansible-playbook ./your_playbook.yml -K`

So, it works: ran and even exec scripts under sudo.
But i can't understand, how can i set what user i use as "executable user".